# Multi-threaded Programming C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have to execute this code manually and figure the output, I tried it out and could not find out what am missing, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *thread_function(void *arg) {
    printf("Hello World :) \n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(void) {

    pthread_t mythread;

    if(pthread_create(&mythread, NULL, thread_function, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failure 1?\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("I have to wait ? \n");

    if (pthread_join(mythread, NULL)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failure 2 ?");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Goodbye Cruel World :(\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is:

```
I have to wait ?
Hello World :)
Goodbye Cruel World :(
```

The output I got:

```
I have to wait ?
Hello World :)
```

Why the code skipped the last print?

Comment: I assume the exit in thread terminates main thread before it prints? Try using pthread_exit instead.

Comment: Exiting the program kills all threads. Either return from the thread function or use the thread exit function.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `exit` in the thread will terminate the process before it has a chance to output the "Goodbye" message. If you want to terminate a thread, use `pthread_exit`, not `exit`.

Comment: Not just "can", but *will* in this case, because the main thread attempts to join the child thread before going on to print the goodbye message, and the child unconditionally calls `exit()`.